# ActionController::UnknownFormat (format.csv)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I know this question has been asked, but for different formats. My concern is with `format.csv`.

**My Try**

Route

```
match '/something.csv' => 'admin#something', via: :get
```

Controller

```
def something
   respond_to do |format|
     format.csv { render text: ["a", "b"].to_csv } #Just a try

     #format.csv { render csv: ["a", "b"].to_csv }
   end
end
```

It throws **ActionController::UnknownFormat**, when I hit `http://localhost:3000/admin/something.csv`

**EDIT**

I was following [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel?autoplay=true), but could find no suggestions to alter routes like Eg:- `defaults: { format: :csv }` (as suggested in **Kajal Ojha's** answer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was facing a same error today and it was resolved by providing a default format in route.

In your case it is

```
match '/something.csv' => 'admin#something', via: :get, defaults: { format: :csv }
```

Comment: Likely, the link you are using does not have the following in parentheses at the end ... admin_something_path(:format => "csv") ... so the router may be guessing html (your controller only has csv, no html option).  The default csv-format in the route fix works, because it sets this without it being explicitly declared in the link to that route.

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding this `request.format = :csv` before `respond_to`

```
request.format = :csv

respond_to do |format|
  format.csv { render text: ["a", "b"].to_csv }
end
```